# java - operator & not defined for types (boolean, int)

Tags: java, operators, syntax-error

i'm converting a c++ header to java and the following does not work.
opstring is a string and alumacOP is a string array. opindex is an int.

```
opstring = alumacOP[opindex][(op >> 11) & 3 == 3]; //code does not work.
```

this does not work for some reason. it's not the algorithm, but eclipse saying that '&' is not defined for types boolean and int.

so my question is: Why does logical AND reference only Boolean values in java? because this works:

```
boolean boola,boolb;
if(boola & boolb)
  return;
```

but not this (eclipse still throws an error:

```
int x = 9, y = 8;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  if(x & y = i)
    return;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on operator precedence.

```
opstring = alumacOP[opindex][(((op >> 11) & 3) == 3)?1:0];
```

is what you want. (note the parenthesis around &, and the ?: to convert bool to int.

Comment: that would work, but the it is impossible to tell what the output values of would be, since the c++ code never the ? operator. the algorithm that i typed above i copied directly from the header of the c++ program

Comment: The C++ auto-converts the boolean `(op >> 11) & 3 == 3` to an integer (1 for true, 0 for false) for indexing.  You have to do that conversion explicitly in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The & you see is the bitwise AND, not the logical AND.

And the reason you see that it throws an error is because your if statement conditional is an assignment, not a check.

You need to use 2 equal signs (==) such as it says if (x & y == i)

Comment: To add to this, reference the documentation on bitwise and logical operators here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2

Answer (score 0):

In java you can do `&` on two `boolean`s or two `int`s, but you can't do it on one of each.  Also watch for your order of operations, and the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: Keith, the original C++ code used the exact same algorithm, and it compiled fine. is this a thing with java itself?

Comment: Java is not C++, C++ is not Java.  They are different languages.  It's not a "thing" with Java, Java is defined to work differently from C++.

Comment: This is a thing where C++ and Java differ.  Don't expect them to be the same language when they aren't.  The C++ works because it does automatic conversion from bool to int and vice versa.  Those conversions have to be explicit in Java.